# Proof for $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left(x\right)$, as $f= \dfrac{1}{n}$, if $x \in A_{n}$, and $f=0$ if $x \notin A_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I just wanted to ask, if this is the correct way to prove this limit. My confusion comes from the fact, that I found one solution, and it was much more complex than mine. So I am not sure if I misunderstood the exercise, or just did something wrong.

The exercise is:
Suppose that $A_{n}$ is, for each natural number $n$, some $finite$ set of numbers in $\left[0,1\right]$, and that $A_{n}$ and $A_{m}$ have no members in common if $m \ne n$. Define $f$ as follows:

$f\left(x\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}$, $x$ in $A_{n}$.

$f\left(x\right)=0$, $x$ not in $A_{n}$, for any $A_{n}$.

Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left(x\right)=0$ for all $a$ in $\left[0,1\right]$.

As I understood this problem we can just appeal that any set $A_{n}$ cannot have any elements, so the proof follows as:

Let us assume that there is some $a_{\alpha}$, and this $a_{\alpha} \in A_{\alpha}$, and let say that it is the only element in this set. Then $f\left(a_{\alpha}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\alpha}$, and for all other $x$, as $x \ne a_{\alpha}$, $f\left(x\right)=0$.

Then there too is set $A_{\beta}$, this set has element $a_{\beta} \in A_{\beta}$ and, again, it is the only element in this set. So $f\left(a_{\beta}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\beta}$, and for all other $x$, as $x \ne a_{\beta}$, $f\left(x\right)=0$.

But, by a set $A_{\alpha}$, $f\left(a_{\beta}\right)=0$, and by $A_{\beta}$, $f\left(a_{\alpha}\right)=0$. This cannot happen, as then one $x$ would have 2 different values, which cannot be an function. By this, for any set $A_{n}$, $a \notin A_{n}$, for all $a \in \left[ 0,1\right]$.

By this for all $f \left(x\right)$, as $x \in \left[0,1\right]$, $f \left(x\right)=0$.

So, $\left| f \left(x\right)-l \right| <\epsilon$, then $\left|l \right| <\epsilon$, and as $ 0< \epsilon$, then $l=0$.

In conclusion, $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left(x\right)=0$ for all $a$ in $\left[0,1\right]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have misunderstood the exercise: for each $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x)$ has a well-defined value.

- Either $x$ belongs to one of the $A_n$. Then $f(x) = 1/n$. Note that there is no ambiguity here, since $x$ cannot belong to two different sets $A_n$ and $A_m$.
- Or $x$ does not belong to any of the $A_n$, and then $f(x) = 0$.

Think for instance that $A_n$ is just the one-element set $A_n = \{1/n\}$. Then $f(x) = 0$ for any $x$, except $f(1) = 1$, $f(1/2) = 1/2$, $f(1/3)  = 1/3$, etc. In this case, can you prove the given statement? In particular, show that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0.
$$
You probability need to go back to the $\epsilon / \delta$ definition of limit for this. Then, try to generalize.

Comment: But then, if it went as you said, then the $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left( a_{\alpha} \right)=\dfrac{1}{\alpha}$ at some point (assuming this limit can even exist, we can't assure that, as in close vicinity there can be infinitely many $\dfrac{1}{\beta}$, and some of these can be $\dfrac{1}{\beta}> \epsilon$). So if we choose this approach, I think there is no $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right)=0 $, at least not for $all$ $a \in \left[0,1\right]$.

Comment: There can indeed be infinitely many $1/\beta$ near a point, but not too many that are too large! The crux of the argument is that since each $A_n$ is finite, then in a neighborhood of a point, there are only be finitely many points of $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$. Therefore, all points in a small enough neighborhood will belong to either none of the sets $A_k$, or to some set $A_k$ with $k > n$, and thus the values will be small.

Comment: @ Raoul Yes, but still, the $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right) \ne 0$ for all $ a \in \left[ 0,1 \right]$. I am not saying that there are no limits, I am just saying, that not all of these limits are zero.

Comment: Why do you say that the limit is not zero? The value at a point $a$ does not matter when computing the limit at $a$. What I am saying here is that if you look close enough to a point $a$ (not at $a$), then the value of the function are either 0, or very small (since close enough, you only have points of $A_n$ with $n$ large). This can be made formal with $\epsilon / \delta$, I can write it up if you wish.

Comment: No thanks, I already understood my mistake. Do not know how I could have missed something so fundamental.